# How to determine location in code where segfault occurred using syslog message?

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I have some code that can't be run under `GDB` because it's an embedded system. However, in the `syslog` I will occasionally see the following:

```
kernel: nam[13986]: segfault at b579000 ip b71737dc sp b5120c9c error 4 in libc-2.5.so[b7102000+13f000]
```

Is there some way to find where in the code this error occurred using the numbers listed in the error output above?

Comment: Besides going back from ip to discover in which libc function your application crashed, you can enable core files with "ulimit -c unlimited", then waiting for program to crash, transfer core file to your pc and debug with "gdb yourapp -c core".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ip` stands for "instruction pointer", and it's the location of the crash. In the quoted message, it's `0xb71737dc`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I convert that IP to the offending line of source code?

Comment: You will need debugging symbols for the application/library you're examining, and your favourite debugger. In moderate optimisation levels, this may not do the trick, so you might have to do some manual labour - debugging the disassembly or matching it to the offending code. If you have other sort of information like e.g. `strace` output, it can also help you figure out the control flow before the crash.